# Android Studio - Android Project View is Missing

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I've found some webpage but it does not guide me back to normal android project view.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-androidview.html

I did **File** => **Other Settings** => **Default Project Structure** => **Default Settings** => **OK** It make even worse, import library become not function-able.

Comment: Did you create a new project in AndroidStudio or import an existing one?

Comment: Try creating a new project to see if "Android Project View" is available. if it is, then most probably the project you opened is corrupted or not a gradle build (or missing .iml)

Comment: @benjaminScharbau Yes. I did create new project, try to import manually. But after I create project, "Android Project View" still not appear.

Answer (score 18):

I also had this problem (creating new project also looked similar to IntelliJ IDEA), got it fixed when I enabled some Android-related plugins.

Go to **Preferences** (**Settings** on Windows and Linux) > **Plugins** and enable **Android Support**, at a minimum.

Now you will have "Android" option in the **Project View**.

Comment: After a pc crash the Android view disappeared next time I started Android Studio. This Answer worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This solution saved my day

Comment: I needed to edit my project hierarchy due to using Product Flavors. But then I couldn't figure out how to restore the old "Android" project view until this - thanks!

Comment: This solution worked for me.  On android studio 3.2.1 the menu to enable the Android plugins was at: File->Settings...->Plugins

Comment: This solution didn't work for me using android studio 3.6.3.  I now longer find a menu item to enable Android plugins.

Comment: Where is "Preferences" menu option?

Comment: @giorgio79 apologies for replying so late. I think on MacOS it is "Preferences", but on Windows and Linux it is "Settings".

Answer (score 9):

Try:

**View -> Tool Windows -> Project** OR the shortcut is **alt+1**.

If that's not working try:

**Window -> Restore Default Layout** OR the shortcut is **shift+F12**.

Also, check that Studio is up to date:

**Help -> Check for update...**

Comment: @DigitlNinja Not working. It still remain the same view.

Comment: @TxuverJhiWei Try what I added to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

None of the above solutions worked for me so I fixed this by removing the *.gradle* and *.idea* folders from my project.

Comment: Brilliantly simple and effective!

Comment: This worked for me. I did not find mussing plugins. I had project, that was last edited years ago with older version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The square at the bottom left corner of android studio lets you spread the screen or it populates it with side menus.]

The square at the bottom left corner of android studio lets you spread the screen or it populates it with side menus.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happened when I used Kotlin KTS for Gradle files, but created a java library module for this project. After trying to reimport project I got an error:

> New Gradle Sync is not supported due to containing buildSrc module

**Solution**:
Migrate added module to kts
Remove created by Wizard `settings.gradle`, if you already use `settings.gradle.kts`
Reimport project
**File** -> Close project
**Android Studio**: import project
Show it your current project location

Answer (score 1):

Just had the problem happen to me again.  I got the problem solved, but unfortunately I can't confirm the solution, now that it's fix; but I have strong suspicions on what was the cause.

In my case, the problem occurred as a result of reorganizing my project directory.  My projects are stored in given directory lets call it "Projects".  I renamed that fold to "ProjectsBackup" and created a new "Projects" directory. I then moved selected projects now contained in the "ProjectBackup" directory to the new "Projects" directory.  After moving the first project, I used Android Studio to open that project.  That's when the problem occurred.  I got a message that it couldn't find the gradle-wrapper and offered me the choice to create it.  The gradle-wrapper is stored in a directory call "gradle" and its stored in the "Projects" directory. I had not copied that directory over from the "ProjectsBackup" to the new "Projects" directory.  At the time, I thought nothing about that since, a new one was created.  After trying all the various suggestion in this problem discussion, android studio offered a notification from me to update my "android gradle" plugin.  I did the update and after that the "android" view was now available for me to select.  The android gradle update fixed the problem.

I unfortunately, can't tell you what changed as a result of the update, nor can I tell you how you can force Android Studio to update or reinstall the android gradle plugin.  All I can tell you is that I got lucky that android studio gave me that notification to update the android gradle plugin.  Things like "file/project structure" and changing the Android Gradle Plugin Version, didn't fix the problem.  What I did notice, was that when I first looked at that, the drop-down list of android gradle versions was an empty list.  I manually put one in "3.6.3", but it didn't help.  If you run into this problems I would suggest you look at the dates of the two file in the "wrapper" directory and compare those to projects you may have that are working correctly with the android view.  I wish I would have checked the date of the wrapper jar file, when it wasn't working. That's what I think might have been wrong (i.e. I got a wrapper.jar file that was incompatible with my version of android studio - unfortunately I can't prove that)

Comment: I just tried reduplicate the problem going through the same steps.  I tried it several times and I just couldn't duplicate the problem.  I wonder if the problem was cause by letting android studio add the wrapper automatically, and it added a wrapper for the a gradle version, which isn't installed?  ie. it got installed when I did the update!

Comment: Yeah, I thinks that what's happening.  I looked at the time and date of my gradle-wrapper.properties file and it was created and last modified at the time I was offered the wrapper to be automatically updated.  In it I see this: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip  and that didn't get installed till the update was offered later on.  So there's a time delay.

Comment: Just a tip: It's nice if you always write the path to a file or directory, such as "the 'wrapper' directory"... Say "the 'android/gradle/wrapper' directory" instead! It really helps the applying of your answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

problem solve i have click this button