# Android Studio android tab is missing

Tags: android-studio

In android studio the android tab is missing and i can't reach or open the java classes and layouts files. 
Also tried to uninstall/install android studio.
[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER2DW.png)

Comment: Can you include your IDE screenshot? Also, look at these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961397/android-studio-new-project-missing-folders 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817556/android-studio-android-project-view-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a new project, you might be having issues with Gradle. If its a pre-existing project, there might be something wrong with the project itself.

Comment: I think it's obvious that there is *something* wrong with the project.