# Android Studio project structure item missing from file menu

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I recently had to re-import my flutter project from my git repo and everything is working fine except for the project structure missing from the file menu. It should be at File -> Project Structure but it's simply gone. Can't find any answers elsewhere. Have I missed something when re-importing the project?

[screenshot of what my menu looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNiLk.jpg)

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817556/android-studio-android-project-view-is-missing/42113078  first result in google

Comment: Guess queries project view and project structure give different search results
Edit: Not related to my issue either

Comment: you can create a new project, and coppy lib and pubspec.yaml and assets(if any) into the new one)

Comment: How did you sole it?

Comment: Sorry @Noor, can’t remember.

Answer (score 1):

1- Delete `.idea\modules.xml` file.

2- Close your project and open it again.