# In android studio, under android -> app -> src -> main -> res. Then under ‘New’ select ‘Image Asset’ is not showing up. What's the work around?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

[image]

How can one change the size of the app launcher icon in Flutter if by right clicking on "res" and "new" and there's no "image asset" option is showing up. Is there a work around? Does anybody know?

Comment: Have you tried it from the **Android** view?

Comment: No. How do you do that?

Comment: On the top left corner, you'll `Project` (the view you see now). There is a drop-down menu and you should see `Android`.

Comment: No, there's no android in drop-down menu. I am not seeing "Image-asset" in res and could it be cus' of I haven't downloaded Android emulator?

Comment: Refer to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817556/android-studio-android-project-view-is-missing/42113078) if you cannot find it and not downloading Android emulator shouldn't be an issue. (I assume you're trying to make an **XML** file in a proper folder.)

Comment: No, I am not doing that. I am just trying to change the size of the app icon in flutter. It's not working. That's the process which I mention

Comment: You can go back to the **Project** view anytime you want ;; You mentioned that you could not see the `Image Asset` option, so I just provided a possible solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the application launcher icon on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter)