# Android Project View is not showing in Android Studio Iguana under the Projects dropdown

Tags: android-studio

I would like to request you to please advise me on how to display the Android View under the Project structure, in Android Studio Iguana.
Please see the attached screenshot:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_nJDGOUveIXFdIkFv7U6OyLdZx-5t4rw/view?usp=sharing
This Android View usually used to show in all the previous versions.

I tried the following:

1. I checked Youtube Videos, and various forums, but was unable to find how to enable the Android View in Android Studio Iguana.
2. I found one old post(year 2015) in Stackoverflow which is similar to my issue, but, i have already done what they have suggested. [Android Studio - Android Project View is Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817556/android-studio-android-project-view-is-missing)
   ie, enable Android Plugins: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O3AEC4oMdtB22_D8moDVumbB6gb5G8rs/view?usp=sharing
3. i also tried restoring to default layout as suggested in the above StackOverflow post:
   "View -> Tool Windows -> Project OR the shortcut is alt+1.
   If that's not working try:
   Window -> Restore Default Layout OR the shortcut is shift+F12.
   Also, check that Studio is up to date:
   Help -> Check for update..."

but the above did not help either.

Would really appreciate your help.